# MySQL display time as Text

Tags: mysql

I've tried this query but it didn't meet my requirements.

Code:

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(time(created_on) + 0  ,'-',year(created_on) ,dayofyear(created_on)) as serialno 
FROM tables 
WHERE id = '29';
```

The time is 07:14:52 (hh:mm:ss) and it is displayed as 71452 but i want it to be displayed only as 0714.

The year, which is displayed as 2018 should be displayed as 18.

Comment: Consider returning the datetime to the .net/c# code, that way you can use datetime related functions and when displaying it you can set the desired format. Check this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime_ToString_System_String_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DATE_FORMAT(date, pattern) from MySQL:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT("2017-06-15 08:14:52", "%H%m");
```

Returns `0814`

And to display `17` as year:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT("2017-06-15 08:14:52", "%y");
```

Comment: where should I put the "%H%m" in the query ? 

Thankyou

Comment: Instead of your CONCAT(..) use something like `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_on, "%h%m) as serialno FROM tables WHERE id = '29'`